# Does a class instance that shares access between coroutines need a asyncio Lock?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

For a project I am writing a class that holds data to be shared by multiple coroutines, a basic example would be:

```py
import copy

class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ls = []
        self.tiles = {}

    def add(self, element):
        self.ls.append(element)

    def rem(self, element):
        self.ls.remove(element)

    def set_tiles(self, t):
        self.tiles = t

    def get_tiles(self):
        return copy.deepcopy(self.tiles)
```

And it would be used like this:

```py
async def test_coro(d):
    # Do multiple things including using all methods from d

test_data = Data()

# Simultaneously start many instances of `test_coro` passing `test_data` to all of them
```

I'm struggling to understand when you would need to use a lock in a situation like this, my question about this code is would I need to use an asyncio Lock at all, or would it be safe as all variable access / assigning happens without any awaiting inside the class?

Comment: In asyncio code does not run simultaneously even if it seems to do. Everything is scheduled one after the other in an event loop. (But that does not a apply if you spawn threads or similar.)

Comment: the state of `Data` may change if `await` is evaluated because another `test_coro` may kick in. So, you are safe between (explicit and implicit) `await`s.